# add single quotes to a variable to a line in bash

Tags: unix

I have a function `get_info_using_api` which calls one more function`get_data` 
Function `get_data` takes some parameters and executes a curl command
here are the contents

```
function get_data() {
    local http_method="${1}"
    local rest_call_url="${2}"
    local other_paramas="${3}"
    curl -s -k "${other_paramas}" -X $http_method $rest_call_url
}
```

now my `get_info_using_api` looks something like this

```
function get_info_using_api {
    local api_key=${1}
    local other_curl_options="-H "'Content-Type:application/json'" -H "'X-user:'$api_key''""
    local http_method=GET
    local url=something
    data=$(get_curl_data $http_method $jenkins_url "${other_curl_options}")
}
```

so when i call this function `get_info_using_api` the curl command that gets executed is 
`curl -s -k '-H Content-Type:application/json -H user:api_key' -X GET url`

whereas what i need is 
`curl -s -k '-H Content-Type:application/json' -H 'user:api_key' -X GET url`

i am trying to add these single quotes in the line but i am not able to.
Can someone help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

Put them in an array.

```
function get_info_using_api {
    local api_key="${1}"
    local other_curl_options=(
        "-H 'Content-Type:application/json'"
        "-H 'X-user:$api_key'"
    )
    local http_method=GET
    local url=something
    data=$(get_curl_data $http_method $jenkins_url "${other_curl_options[@]}")
}
```

You can literally embed the singles inside the doubles, and when you quote the array with the `"${x[@]}"` syntax it will return the args as separate strings.

You can test the logic with this:

```
$: x=( 1 2 3 )
$: printf "%s\n" "${x[@]}"
1
2
3
```

Each gets printed separately.